# MinGW ld.exe can't find GCC include, permission denied

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, mingw32

I'm trying to build this stupid library https://github.com/LRN/libntlink so I can use it in a porting projects, and its given me nothing but trouble so far. This time the linker can't seem to access the gcc include folder. Here's the error

```
gcc  c:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include;c:/MinGW/include -I. -O3 -fno-common
-Wall -mms-bitfields -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x600 -o juncpoint.o -c juncpoint.c
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot fin
d c:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can post the whole makefile, but it may be easier and cleaner to go to the github page, since the makefile is a little lengthy. I checked the stuff I found, nothing else is using ld or whatever, and the folder in question has the square for read only, which iirc means its not read only. I've tried running the command at an elevated level every way I know how. Nothing has worked.

EDIT: It does this for all folders, if you specify them as the input file for ld. The thing is written wrong maybe? I'm not sure what its trying to do with that.

Comment: Did you try changing the permissions on the 'include' directory?

Comment: The permissions are set to full access for everyone

Comment: Typo in path name?  compare "c:/MinGW/lib/gcc/..."  to "c:/mingw/bin/../lib/..." or maybe you have 2 installations ... nad should not mix them.

Comment: I don't think so? I typed in the whole path it gives for ld.exe and it gets to the right place. I'm not sure what you're saying there

Comment: Oh. I forgot Windows is generally not case sensitive. ... sorry.

Comment: "ld" is probably the "gnu linker".  (You should be able to invoke it as "ld --version")   It is what I would expect mingw to run.   However, on Ubuntu my make files never mention "ld".  Sorry I have not been much help.  Been too long since I used mingw on Windows.

Comment: One more idea - 15+ yrs ago mingw did a poor job of naming their (?)dll's.  Our team had some older tools based on earlier mingw, and if those tools were loaded prior to running the latest tool suite's compile or linker, and the names conflicted, things did not work.  I think reset was necessary.  I don't remember a solution, I think when you wanted to  build you reset your PC and then made sure to not run any of the old tools (and vice-versa).  But, that was a long time ago.